# sed remove command - Include upper/lower case

Tags: sed

I am using the following command to get rid of lines that contain `hotmail`

```
sed -i '/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*hotmail/d' ./file
```

The test data is

```
"foxva****omes****","scott@hotmail.com","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
"foxva****omes****","scott@HotMAil.cOm","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
"foxva****omes****","scott@HOTMAIL.COM","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
```

This currently only deletes the first line. The second and third line do not get removed because they contain capitals. How can I change so that it's not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i '/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*hotmail/dI' ./file
```

If you're not using modern GNU sed, however, you may be stuck with this:

```
sed -i '/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*[hH][oO][tT][mM][aA][iI][lL]/d' ./file
```

[This link to the GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) explains `I` and other modifiers.

Comment: `sed -e '/[hH][oO][tT][mM][aA][iI][lL]/d'` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

sed has a I flag you can add for case-insensitive match.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157288/using-sed-to-delete-a-case-insensitive-matched-line